# How to compare multiple columns under same row in a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Following columns of a table should not be equal in my where clause.

- cd_delivery_address
- cd_mail_delivery_address
- cd_st_code
- cd_mail_st_code
- cd_zip
- cd_mail_zip

Please find my code snippet to achieve this:

```
     select * from table cd
     where
(
(cd_mail_delivery_address <> cd_delivery_address or    
(cd_mail_delivery_address is null and cd_delivery_address is not null) or
(cd_mail_delivery_address is not null and cd_delivery_address is null)
)
and (
cd.cd_city <> cd.cd_mail_city or 
(cd.cd_city is null and cd_mail_city is not null) or 
(cd_city is not null and cd_mail_city is null))
and (
cd.st_code <> cd.cd_mail_st_code or 
(cd.st_code is null and cd_mail_st_code is not null) or 
(st_code is not null and cd_mail_st_code is null)
)
and (
cd.cd_zip <> cd.cd_mail_zip or 
(cd.cd_zip is null and cd_mail_zip is not null) or 
(cd_zip is not null and cd_mail_zip is null)
)
)
```

All columns are varchar2 and i get correct output for this code. But is it a better way to compare multiple columns in pl sql? can i improve this code? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your null checks with NVL function something like this:

```
...
NVL(cd_mail_delivery_address,'_') <> NVL(cd_delivery_address,'_')
...
```

it's definitively more readable but I'm not sure about query efficency

Answer (score 0):

I have done it for two columns using a join:

```
select a.cd_delivery_address,b.cd_mail_delivery_address 
from cd a inner join cd b 
where a.cd_delivery_address <> b.cd_mail_delivery_address and
a.cd_delivery_address = b.cd_delivery_address
```

Here null checking condition will be omitted and will reduce the number of conditions, but there is a performance impact since join is involved.